# eGalax touchscreen + Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, touchscreen

I've attached an Iiyama T1731SR-W1 17" touchscreen with HDMI and USB to my fully-updated Raspberry Pi. The touch isn't working plug-and-play and spent hours to try to get it working.

**lsusb**

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0eef:0001 D-WAV Scientific Co., Ltd eGalax TouchScreen
```

**evtest /dev/input/event0** + one touch at the screen

```
Event: time 1514922218.165932, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0042  
Event: time 1514922218.165932, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 1  
Event: time 1514922218.165932, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 0 (ABS_X), value 3612  
Event: time 1514922218.165932, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 556  
Event: time 1514922218.165932, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------  
Event: time 1514922218.175900, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 554  
Event: time 1514922218.175900, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------  
Event: time 1514922218.181900, type 3 (EV_ABS), code 1 (ABS_Y), value 552  
Event: time 1514922218.181900, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------  
Event: time 1514922218.237903, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value d0042  
Event: time 1514922218.237903, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 330 (BTN_TOUCH), value 0  
Event: time 1514922218.237903, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
```

**dmesg** gives an error but i'm not sure if it has anything to do with

```
[    3.612578] hid-multitouch 0003:0EEF:0001.0001: failed to fetch feature 7  

[    3.613008] input: eGalax Inc. USB TouchController Pen as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:0EEF:0001.0001/input/input0  

[    3.614540] input: eGalax Inc. USB TouchController as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:0EEF:0001.0001/input/input1  

[    3.736799] raspberrypi-touchscreen 3f700000.dsi.0: Unknown Atmel firmware revision: 0xfa
```

**cat /proc/bus/input/devices**

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=0eef Product=0001 Version=0210  
N: Name="eGalax Inc. USB TouchController Pen"  
P: Phys=usb-3f980000.usb-1.2/input0  
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.0/0003:0EEF:0001.0001/input/input0  
U: Uniq=  
H: Handlers=mouse0 event0  
B: PROP=0  
B: EV=1b  
B: KEY=c01 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  
B: ABS=3  
B: MSC=10
```

---

So I think the device is properly recognised but the cursor isn't moving while I touch the screen. I've been trying to calibrate the screen with *xinput_calibrator* but this tool doesn't recognise the touch events either.

I'm using kernel 4.9.59-v7+

Please help

Comment: Try first `sudo rpi-update;sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` then try again ... it looks like there is something wrong with the revision of the driver?! ... or better follow manufecturers manual for the installation

Comment: I forgot to tell that I've done that already :). Following manufacturer automated driver install doesn't work either

Comment: mine is `Linux 4.9.70-v7+` then you have to do at least `sudo rpi-update` then reboot and check again

Comment: It says `Your firmware is already up to date`

Comment: Are you using NOOBS or Raspbian on the rpi3 ... or something else ...? Had many problems with NOOBS ... I 've changed to raspbian and many things fixed on low level device management ... like usb hungs and UART synchronization and such

Comment: I've tested this with a custom build kernel and with Raspbian 4.9 (currently latest). Same results...

Comment: Tried to use another rpi3 board?

Comment: Yes, I've tried another Rpi 3

Comment: It is a `try and fail` situation so after all try to unplug the mouse then reboot ... if touchscreen still does not working then try play with the `/boot/config.txt` by adding the line `max_usb_current=1` first then reboot ... if still not ... unplug anything even the keyboard exept touchscreen ... if still not ... change values on the `hdmi_` options ... and so on

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I can see the input events on /dev/input/event2 using evtest. But somehow those events are not used. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same issue.
I finally fixed it, with the help of a Dutch forum:
https://zeilersforum.nl/index.php/forum-125/73-stroom-elektrische-apparatuur-aan-boord/574771-faytech-touch-op-raspberry-pi-werkt-niet?start=25#841523

It boils down to:

- First install evdev:

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev

- change the driver in a config file:

> sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf

```
at the lines with touchscreen driver replace libinput by evdev
```

- reboot

Comment: Important to note, when you replace "libinput" for "evdev", you may need to replace all occurrences. This is because (at least on my configuration), udev tags the touchscreen as a mouse.